# ItextSharp MVC5 C# - text in front of existing pdf

Tags: c#, file, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

I'm building a web app for editing PDF files using iTextSharp.

When I try to write to the PDF, the text is getting printed behind an existing content, however I need to print it on top of it.

Can someone explain to me how can I set a depth property for my text?

This is my code

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(oldFile))
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        document.Open();

        try
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            cb.BeginText();
            try
            {
                cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 100);
                cb.ShowText("Customer Name");
            }
            finally
            {
                cb.EndText();
            }

            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This how the pdf looks like, one word is behind the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me how can I set a depth property for my text?

Pdf does not have an explicit depth or z-axis property. What is drawn first, therefore, is covered by what is drawn later.

So if you want to have the template under your added text, you should pull the code adding the template before the code adding the text:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

cb.BeginText();
try
{
    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12);
    cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 100);
    cb.ShowText("Customer Name");
}
finally
{
    cb.EndText();
}
```

Alternatively you can make use of am itextsharp feature: it actually created two content streams, the direct content and the under content, and puts the under content before the direct content.

Thus, if rearranging the code as above is not an option for you, you can instead add the background to the under content instead of the direct content.

Comment: It didn't worked for me, still text is overlapped by previous content...

Comment: @AamirNakhwa *"still text is overlapped by previous content"* - that is impossible in case of code like the code this question is about. Thus, your issue is different. You should make it a question in its own right and provide all the relevant information. And be generous with the information you share as you appear not to have recognized what is relevant and what not, otherwise you would have seen that the context of this question does not match yours.

Comment: I am having same situation as him, adding text in existing pdf but old content is overlapping the newly added text. Please have a look at this link https://ibb.co/KbVwPp0

Comment: @AamirNakhwa You should make it a question in its own right and provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the link https://ibb.co/KbVwPp0
Barbara is cutting off

Comment: @AamirNakhwa You should make it a question in its own right and provide all the relevant information. (An image is of no help at all, provide the pivotal code and a sample PDF with which to reproduce the issue.)